# How to build multiple Cython files into one python extension

Tags: python, cython

Currently I have one **pyx** file contains all classes (parent class and children classes). now I want to break it down into multiple files, one file for the parent class, and each child class has it own file.
So two things I want to know

1. How do I import the parent class in the child class file?
2. What need to be changed in the **setup.py**, in order to build the extension?

**setup.py** look like

```
from distutils.core import setup

from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("MyLibrary.pyx"))
```

I have google it, but what I got is how to build multiple extensions at once. Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out it is pretty easy. I even don't need to change the **setup.py**
I just moved the children classes' code to their own files and include them from the parent class.

It would became something like this

- **Child1.pyx**
- **Child2.pyx**
- **Child3.pyx**
- **MyLibrary.pyx**

and in the **MyLibrary.pyx**

```
.
.
.
include Child1.pyx
include Child2.pyx
include Child3.pyx

class parent:
.
.
.
```